# How to create a list of dictionary objects of unknown value type?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

I'm creating a `CInformation` class that will include various types of information. One type of the information it will expose are `Parameters`. Each parameter can be typed with any of the following types: `int`, `short`, `string`. Additionally, any `parameter` may have several possible values based on a `string` key. So I thought of creating a `Dictionary<string, T>` to hold all possible values for a parameter, but the problem arises when I try to declare my `Parameters` list. I created the following classes:

```
public class CParameter<T>
{ 
    public object ParameterType { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string,T> ValueByString;
}

public class CInformation
{
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public List<CParameter<object>> Parameters; // cannot cast any of my types to object, obviously!
}
```

Any suggestions how I could get around my issue? I open to different solutions to my problem, not necessarily the same design I have above. Thank you.

**EDIT:** The main feature I want to achieve is to be able to have a list of dictionaries of different value types.

Comment: Can you make `CInformation<T>` also generic and make `public List<CParameter<T>> Parameters;` . I'm not sure if I understood your problem

Comment: You probably also want to change `CParameter.ParameterType` to `T` from `object`.

Comment: Not realy, because `Parameters` list is supposed to have multiple CParameter objects and each one be of a different type.
EDIT: Yes, you are right about `ParameterType`.

Comment: Ok then, the obvious question is what messages do you want to send them? What roles (interfaces) do you expect all of them to implement? If none - you can make a generic type [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) and implicitly cast it to object. If you want to interact with all of these objects via some protocol - just declare `List<CParameter<IMyInterface>> Parameters;`. You need to reconsider if generics are a good approach here. Again, you need to explain your problem domain in more details, so that we could give you a more concrete answer.

Comment: The important feature I want to have is that each parameter needs to be of a certain type (`int`, `short`, or `string`). and each parameter has multiple values keyed by string keys, hence the dictionary. I'm not sure what you mean by making the generic type covariant.

Comment: There is a link [behind the term](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) I highly recommend to at least loosely understand it before using generics.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov, I'm not sure if I could be more specific in my problem definition. Again, the main feature I want to achieve is to be able to have a list of dictionaries of different value types. And thank you for mentioning `covariance` here, I had no knowledge of the concept. On another note, I was trying to avoid interfaces and use standard types where I can for other design considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `object` to specialize a generic type is rather suspicious. If you do that, you might as well not even use a generic type at all. :-)

I think the issue here is that you want your instances of `CParameter<T>` to be specialized for different parameter types, and you want the parameters list on the `CInformation` class to contain different kinds of `CParameter<T>`.

In other words:

```
namespace Scratch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CParameter<int> ints = new CParameter<int>();
            CParameter<long> longs = new CParameter<long>();
            CInformation info = new CInformation();
            info.AddParameter(ints);
            info.AddParameter(longs);
            CParameter<int> ints2 = info.GetParameter<int>();

            // ints2 and ints will both refer to the same CParameter instance.
        }
    }

    public class CParameter<T>
    {
        public Type ParameterType { get { return typeof(T); } }

        public Dictionary<string, T> ValueByString;
    }

    public class CInformation
    {
        public string Version { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        private List<object> parameters;

        public CInformation()
        {
            this.parameters = new List<object>();
        }

        public void AddParameter<T>(CParameter<T> parameter)
        {
            this.parameters.Add(parameter);
        }

        public CParameter<T> GetParameter<T>()
        {
            foreach (object parameter in this.parameters)
            {
                if (parameter is CParameter<T>)
                    return (CParameter<T>)parameter;
            }

            throw new Exception("Parameter type " + typeof(T).FullName + " not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `List<object>` in that example could just as well be an `ArrayList`.

Also, I have a hunch that you're going to want to retrieve those `CParameter` objects by name rather than just by type. So consider adding a Name property to `CParameter`, and a name parameter to the `GetParameter` method. Then iterate over the list to find the property with the right name. Casting the result before returning it will verify that the type is the one you expected.

Or better yet, store the parameters in a `Dictionary<string,object>` instead of just a list, and use the parameter names as keys.